# Implementación de método en Java guarda dos veces un vehículo

Tags: java, array, poo, netbeans, class

Tengo un enunciado de una aplicación. Y un apartado de ese enunciado es el siguiente:

insertarVehiculo: Recibe todos los datos de un vehículo y trata de insertarlo en el concesionario. Devuelve 0 si se hizo con éxito, -1 si el concesionario está vacío y -2 si la matrícula ya existe.

Y he implementado este método:

```
public int insertarVehiculo (String marca, String matricula, double numKms) {           // MÉTODO PARA INSERTAR UN VEHÍCULO EN EL ARRAY.
    
    int valorDevuelto = -1;             // Variable tipo int. Devuelve -1 si el concesionario está vacío, 0 si el vehículo se ha insertado
                                        // correctamente y -2 si la matrícula ya existe.
    
        coches[numCoches] = new Vehiculo();
        coches[numCoches].setMarca(marca);
        coches[numCoches].setMatricula(matricula);
        coches[numCoches].setNumKms(numKms);
        numCoches ++;

    return valorDevuelto;
}           // FIN DEL MÉTODO insertarVehiculo().
```

¿Qué quieren decir con devolver -2, -1 y 0? Tengo que hacer que devuelva un entero y dependiendo del resultado poner esa variable a uno de los tres enteros que piden?

¿Se puede utilizar el return, por ejemplo cuando el concesionario está vacío, para utilizarlo en otros métodos (P.e en el main de la clase Principal) para que en otras opciones que tengo (buscaVehiculo) me diga que el concesionario está vacío?

Esta última pregunta la digo porque no me interesaría pasar esos dos datos que pide el método, pero me interesaría el int que devuelve.

También me interesaría utilizar la devolución del -2 para comprobar a la hora de buscar vehículo si existe esa matrícula. Se que lo puedo hacer en otro método o con otra sentencia, pero ya que creo este método, me gustaría poder aprovecharlo. Pero claro, a la hora de buscar vehículo no me interesa meter los kms.

Un saludo. Y gracias.

EDITADO -------

He creado el siguiente código, al ingresar el primer vehículo me devuelve -1. Hasta ahí todo correcto. Pero al ingresar el segundo vehículo con una matrícula diferente, me devuelve el valor -2 pero si que me guarda los datos del vehículo. Además me lo guarda dos veces.

```
public int insertarVehiculo (String marca, String matricula, double numKms) {           // MÉTODO PARA INSERTAR UN VEHÍCULO EN EL ARRAY.
    
    int valorDevuelto = -1;             // Variable tipo int. Devuelve -1 si el concesionario está vacío, 0 si el vehículo se ha insertado
                                        // correctamente y -2 si la matrícula ya existe.
                                        
        if (numCoches == 0) {
            valorDevuelto = -1;
            
            coches[numCoches] = new Vehiculo();
            coches[numCoches].setMarca(marca);
            coches[numCoches].setMatricula(matricula);
            coches[numCoches].setNumKms(numKms);
            numCoches ++;
        } else {
            for (int i = 0; i < numCoches; i ++) {
                if (matricula.equals(coches[i].getMatricula())) {
                    valorDevuelto = -2;
                } else {
                    coches[numCoches] = new Vehiculo();
                    coches[numCoches].setMarca(marca);
                    coches[numCoches].setMatricula(matricula);
                    coches[numCoches].setNumKms(numKms);
                    numCoches ++;
                    
                    valorDevuelto = 0;
                }
            }           // FIN DE BUCLE FOR.
        }
    
        

    return valorDevuelto;
}           // FIN DEL MÉTODO insertarVehiculo().
```

Comment: ¿qué es un concesionario? ¿un array de vehículos? ¿puedes publicar el código de la clase Vehiculo también?

Comment: tu metodo debe hacer uso de un arrayList donde agreges los vehiculos creados y si tu metodo debe devolver un entero,los parametros de tu metodo estan bien pero te falta implementar bucles y condicionales

Comment: Lo que te pide el enunciado es que devuelvas un numero, que representa que es lo que ocurrio. Antes de intentar insertar un vehiculo deberias de validar si el consecionario está vacio (y devolver -1 en ese caso) y validar que el vehiculo no exista (devolviendo -2)

Comment: Explica que es un concesionario para poder darte una respuesta...

Comment: Pero aquí está el meollo de la cuestión. Si introduzco un coche y está vacío, se añadirá y ya no estará vacío.

Comment: @MarceloZárate Sí, un concesionario es una clase donde se almacenará un array de 50 vehículos, los cuales estarán compuestos de atributos de la clase Vehiculo.

Answer (score 1):

El error que tiene tu codigo es que estas buscando y asignando al mismo tiempo por lo cual en cada iteracion del for tu algoritmo busca y si no lo encuentra lo agrega (aunque el vehiculo si este registrado) por esa razon te agrega varias veces el mismo vehiculo, primero tienes que buscar si el vehiculo ya esta registrado y al terminar de buscar dependiendo si esta o no implementas el algoritmo para agregar el auto

```
public int insertarVehiculo (String marca, String matricula, double numKms) 
{           // MÉTODO PARA INSERTAR UN VEHÍCULO EN EL ARRAY.

int valorDevuelto = -1;             // Variable tipo int. Devuelve -1 si el concesionario está vacío, 0 si el vehículo se ha insertado
                                    // correctamente y -2 si la matrícula ya existe.
                                    
    if (numCoches == 0) {
        valorDevuelto = -1;
        
        coches[numCoches] = new Vehiculo();
        coches[numCoches].setMarca(marca);
        coches[numCoches].setMatricula(matricula);
        coches[numCoches].setNumKms(numKms);
        numCoches ++;
    } else {
          //primero buscarmos y si el vehivulo esta registrado asignamos -2
          if(BuscarVehiculo(matricula)){
            valorDevuelto = -2;
          //si no, lo agregamos y regresamos 0
          }else
            {
             coches[numCoches] = new Vehiculo();
             coches[numCoches].setMarca(marca);
             coches[numCoches].setMatricula(matricula);
             coches[numCoches].setNumKms(numKms);
             numCoches ++;
             valorDevuelto = 0;
            }
        }           // FIN DE BUCLE FOR.
    }

    

return valorDevuelto;
}  
//Buscamos el vehiculo por la matricula
public boolean BuscarVehiculo(string matricula)
{
  for (int i = 0; i < numCoches; i ++) 
  { 
     if (matricula.equals(coches[i].getMatricula())
           return true;

     return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Tu método funciona pero al intentar insertar un nuevo vehículo, aunque termina siendo exitoso, también me devuelve el valor -2.

Comment: Lo he arreglado utilizando un switch en el main en vez de if